# Unable to add pageViewController to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I want to add `UIPageController` to `UIView` of `viewController`

Here is my code but it is not working,

MyViewController contains one view which is `_viewExpense` there I want
 to add my `viewcontroller`.

**MyViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

      PageViewControllerDashboard *pageViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MoneyBag" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewControllerDashboard"];

      [self addChildViewController:pageViewController];
      [_viewExpense addSubview:pageViewController.view];
      [pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

**PageViewControllerDashboard**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    pageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 100);


    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}
```

**Page View Controller Data Source**

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((pageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((pageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (pageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    pageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MoneyBag" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

Where i am making mistake please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first mistake that I noticed is inside `PageViewControllerDashboard`,  on this line :

```
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
```

You are setting `dataSource` property of `pageViewController` to `self`. Here your `pageViewController` object is expecting that all its `datasource` methods are declared inside `PageViewControllerDashboard`. Instead all the `datasource` methods are declared inside `PageViewControllerDataSource` class.
So what you should do is initialize an instance of class `PageViewControllerDataSource` like so :

```
PageViewControllerDataSource* pageViewControllerDataSource = [[PageViewControllerDataSource alloc] init]
```

and make this instance of `PageViewControllerDataSource` datasource of `pageViewController`

```
PageViewControllerDataSource* pageViewControllerDataSource = [[PageViewControllerDataSource alloc] init];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = pageViewControllerDataSource;
```

Once you correct the `datasource` property of your `UIPageController` instance, all datasource methods declared inside `PageViewControllerDataSource` will start getting called and your code should also start running as you expected.